# Iterate through website class methods using MSBuild

Tags: asp.net, reflection, msbuild

I am trying to find information on using reflection within a MSBuild task.

I need a way of iterating through the methods of a class contained with a website, at build time. Is this possible? Is MSBuild the best tool to use? Is this an unreasonable requirement, I can't seem to find any documentation on the subject?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Rich

Comment: I'm interested in knowing what you're doing this for.  If you're doing code analysis, FxCop might be a cleaner alternative.

Comment: The big idea is to generate JavaScript signatures for my ASP.NET Web Services, in much the same way the MS AJAX already does. The difference being that I use jQuery and believe I can create the signatures with a smaller foot print.

What I would like to do is create a build task that automatically targets the website being built, iterating through methods marked [ScripMethod]. My issue is that it is very difficult to identify a website's assembly prior to a build. I was hoping their would be a number of environmental variables provided by an MSBUILD library to make this sort of thing easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an extension called [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/). You can execute code from within an msbuild task called script. Using the reflection API your task should be relatively straightforward.

A viable alternative might be [Psake](http://codebetter.com/blogs/james.kovacs/archive/2008/06/27/introducing-psake.aspx) since [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) integrates well with .Net.